# Is there a way disable lax quoting rules in sqlite?

Tags: sqlite, debugging, escaping, literals, double-quotes

It appears that SQLite, apparently as a "compatibility feature", parses double quoted identifiers as string literals if no matching column is found.

I understand that it does so for people who write improper sql, and for backwards compatibility with legacy projects created by such people, but it makes debugging very difficult for those of us writing proper sql on brand new projects.

For example,

```
SELECT * FROM "users" WHERE "usernme" = 'joe';
```

returns a query with 0 rows, since the string 'usernme' does not equal the string 'joe'.

This leaves me scratching my head wondering why i'm not getting joe's row even when i know there's a user by that name until I painstakingly backtrack my code and realize that I left out an a.

Is there any "strict mode" PRAGMA or API option to enforce quoting rules and treat all double-quoted strings as identifiers so that it will inform me immediately if one is misspelled?

(And please, no answers telling me not to quote identifiers if I don't need to, because any such answer is basically telling me that in order to get proper debugging, you have to write bad code in the first place.)

Answer (score 1):

This is hardcoded in the SQLite parser and cannot be changed from the outside.

Answer (score 0):

I also asked in the SQLite channel and someone there was kind enough to look through the source code and create a patch, and even started a thread on the mailing list describing the patch:

http://www.mail-archive.com/sqlite-users@sqlite.org/msg73832.html

It's not an answer that works for the official builds, but it may be someday. For the moment, I'm just going to recompile it myself with this patch.

Comment: I thoroughly tested the patch and can't find any adverse affects to properly written sql code. It looks solid.

Answer (score 0):

Ten years later, and this doesn't completely meet your criteria about "strict mode" kinds of things, but here's a trick I used to make some queries safer, if you can remember to use it. It's to give your table an alias and reference it:

```
SELECT t."nosuch_column" FROM some_table t;
```

I suppose in this form, it's clear to SQLite that a literal isn't desired.